# Grabar android jack externo sonido

Tags: android, soundpool

Buenos días a todos.

Primero perdonad porque pensé que esta pregunta debía ir en ingles, no en español.

Ahora, rectifico y os lo pongo en dicho idioma:

Me gustaría grabar el sonido que entra por la entrada de jack de mi móvil android.

He estado buscando por las diferentes clases de android y he encontrado en la audio capture diferentes preferencias, pero no encuentro donde se puede definir si se usa el micro del teléfono o el externo conectado por jack.

Me gustaría solo utilizar el micro / lo que sea conectado desde el jack.

Hay algun ejemplo? Como debería hacerlo?

- info que he encontrado => https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Gracias

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés y tendría que estar en español.

Comment: Lo siento, pensé que estaba en stackoverflow inglés. Corregido

Comment: No te preocupes. Ahora voto para reabrirla. Gracias por editarla :)